# Subsetting columns based on single value in row

Tags: r

I would like to subset the columns whose 5th row value has the P1 value.

My current approach is as follow:

```
test<- first_sheet[sapply(first_sheet[5,], FUN = function(x){x=="P1" })]
```

However, it is returning the error which states that there are undefined columns selected.

However the logical vector

```
sapply(first_sheet[5,], FUN = function(x){x=="P1" })
```

returns a boolean vector.

May I know what is the cause to this or how would I be able to detect where the issue is? Thanks!

Comment: What about `first_sheet[, sapply(first_sheet[5,], FUN = function(x){x=="P1" })]` ?

Comment: It would help a lot if you would include sample data that can be copy and pasted and then what your expected result is. You could try using one of the sample data sets.

Comment: `x <- iris[sapply(iris[5,], FUN = function(x){x=="setosa" })]`  does what I would expect based on your description (returns just the rows with Species == "setosa") so I suspect you have a different problem.  Are you sure there is at least one TRUE? Also why not just say `x <- iris[iris$Species == "setosa",]`?

Comment: @Elin I ran your code, it's giving dataframe with 1 column from iris df, it contains all rows for Sepecies column.

Comment: this question really needs example data.

Comment: @SN The OP asked for all the rows.

Comment: @SN also my point is that the OP's code does not cause an error message on a known valid data frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**sample data**

```
df <- data.frame( a = 1:10, b = 11:20, c = 5)

#     a  b c
# 1   1 11 5
# 2   2 12 5
# 3   3 13 5
# 4   4 14 5
# 5   5 15 5
# 6   6 16 5
# 7   7 17 5
# 8   8 18 5
# 9   9 19 5
# 10 10 20 5
```

**code**

```
P1 <- 5
df[ , c( df[5, ] == P1 ) ]

#     a c
# 1   1 5
# 2   2 5
# 3   3 5
# 4   4 5
# 5   5 5
# 6   6 5
# 7   7 5
# 8   8 5
# 9   9 5
# 10 10 5
```

**explanation**

`df[5, ] == P1` returns a TRUE/FALSE result row 5 of `df`, TRUE when value == P1
`c( df[5, ] == P1 )` puts this result in a logical vector
`df[ , c( df[5, ] == P1 ) ]` subsets the columns of `df` by this logical vector